# Can I use multiple lines of text in a UIAlertView's button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

At one point in my app, the user has to choose from a list of reasons (it's a medical app that lets one user check if another user gives a patient the right medicine and dose via one or more photos). If the photo is rejected, the user has to choose a reason.

One of our customers provided a list of possible reasons, and they can't be changed. The problem is that one of these reasons is a very long sentence and when I add it to the alertview, the text gets really small instead of just wrapping to a new line. I tried putting a `\n` in my string, but then the second line isn't shown (so it does work, but I only see the first line in the view).

Can I add multiline functionality to the alertview's buttons? I know a `UIButton` does not support multiline. I also know `UIAlertView`'s `addSubView:` does not work anymore since `iOS7`. I'd rather not use any third party libraries, but if I really have to I'm open to suggestions. Increasing the size of the alertview would be an option as well.

Comment: Try my answer...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19789938/how-to-do-a-semi-transparent-modal-segue-like-whatsapp-take-photo-choose-e/19790050#19790050

Comment: _" I know a `UIButton` does not support multiline."_, that is not true at all, you can set multiline text in a `UIButton` instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIAlertView and UIActionSheet are really meant to provide concise feedback and make concise decisions respectively. It sounds like you need a richer interface for the user to make a selection. I would suggest that you create a custom UITableViewController class with a dynamic cell that presents a set of reasons and allows selection of a reason. You could dynamically create a non-editable UITextView to display a multi-line reason and perhaps a button next to the reason to select it. Each row of the UITableView would contain a UIButton to select and a UITextView to show the reason. In your UIableViewController class you would assemble all the reasons relative to the context and then present them in the table view for selection - one row for each possible response. Alternatively, you can forgo the button and just present the reasons via a UITextView. If the user clicks on the row (table cell) you can indicate the response with a check mark

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
```

and capture the selection for processing in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath 
{
    Reason *selectedReason = self.myReasonsArray[indexPath.row];
}
```

[image]

[enter link description here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIAlertView/%22See:%20Alert%20View%22)

Also, UIAlertViews do not support subclassing and have very limited configuration capabilities. I'm suggesting you accomplish your objective by creating a "custom" modal view via a UITableViewController that can be used to essentially popup a rich interface that allows you to do all sorts of things like have multi-line text, images, whatever. You can reuse this view everywhere via delegation.

Comment: Excellent suggestion, however I'm currently working on a custom 'alertview'. I'm gonna need the possibility for extra functionality later on.

Comment: Right, but you shouldn't load up an alert view with a lot of content (it's really not designed for that which is why you are running into issues). See my edit above.

Answer (score 3):

For your requirement it will be better if you use UIActionSheet or Customized PopUp View where you can use multiline.

Comment: Never heard of those, I'm still pretty new to the whole iOS thing. I will take a look at it, thanks.

Comment: [PopUP View](http://code4app.net/category/popupview)  refer this will help you i guess :)

Comment: hmm, I changed my alertview to an actionsheet, but the buttons still have only one line of text. Anything special I need to add?

Comment: i prefer you to go for custom PopUp view than UIAction sheet